# PHP preg_match_all regex for deviding a string

Tags: php, regex

Can anybody help with completing my regex?

I strings which are formatted like this:

```
<FC012D>{p:19}Ja?<BF093C> Du möchtest<BC>zur Königin?<BC><BF040027><BF07>{p:20}<F8012D>Hmm...<BF093C><BC>Du bist gekommen um den<BC>Titel Kriegerin<BC>zu erhalten?<BD><BC>Verstehe.<BF093C> Das ist ganz<BC>schön tapfer für so<BC>eine junge Dame.<BD><BC>Die Königin wird sicher<BC>auch sehr<BC>überrascht sein.<BD><BC>{t:19}Bitte sehr,<BC>geh direkt hinein.<BD><FF>{t:20}Treibe Dich hier nicht<BC>herum, wenn Du hier<BC>nichts zu suchen hast!<BD><FF>
```

I need to split them into an array with preg_match_all to get 3 types of array-elements:

- Strings with <>
- Strings with {}
- Anything else between the other two options as separate elements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
preg_match_all("/<[^>]*>|{(.*?)}|(\(.*?)\)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I need some help with the last option, capturing strings in between.
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kdW

Comment: Do you need `<>` and `{}` in the results? What is the expected output? Also, do you need to keep empty items in the resulting array?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I need them in the results, have a look at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kdW -the only thing missing there is the text between the <> and {} matches. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/preg_split) with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flags and the following regex:

```
'~(<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*})~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WmIh5r/1). It matches and captures into Group 1 two types of substrings:

- `<[^<>]*>` -  `<` followed with 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`
- `{[^{}]*}` -   `{` followed with 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`

The `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` will include all matches into the resulting array. The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will remove unnecessary empty elements.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7BxY4X):

```
$s = '<FC012D>{p:19}Ja?<BF093C> Du möchtest<BC>zur Königin?<BC><BF040027><BF07>{p:20}<F8012D>Hmm...<BF093C><BC>Du bist gekommen um den<BC>Titel Kriegerin<BC>zu erhalten?<BD><BC>Verstehe.<BF093C> Das ist ganz<BC>schön tapfer für so<BC>eine junge Dame.<BD><BC>Die Königin wird sicher<BC>auch sehr<BC>überrascht sein.<BD><BC>{t:19}Bitte sehr,<BC>geh direkt hinein.<BD><FF>{t:20}Treibe Dich hier nicht<BC>herum, wenn Du hier<BC>nichts zu suchen hast!<BD><FF>';
$res = preg_split('~(<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*})~', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: If you need to also match `(...)` substrings, just add an alternative - `'~(<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*}|\([^()]*\))~'`

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much @wiktor. I can 100% work with that. I wish you a great weekend!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now i got to know what you were trying to say... sorry my bad.. perfect answer, today i have learnt PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE, +1 for you.

Comment: Dang it, I had family time... I was going to experiment with these flags for this question!  Well done @WiktorStribiżew as always.